# Let $f(x)$ denote the distance of $x$ from the nearest integer, and $I(k)=[k\pi,k\pi+1]$, find $f(I(k))$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, integers

> For any real number $x$, let $f(x)$ denote the distance of $x$ from the nearest integer. Let $I(k) = [k\pi,k\pi+1]$. Find $f(I(k))$ for all integers $k$.

What I did is

I took greatest integer value $[k\pi]$ then $f(I(k))$ will not have a unique value. 
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x - [k\pi] &  x<[k\pi] + 1/2, x\in I(k)\\
|x - [k\pi+1]| & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $f(x)$ is a periodic function with period $1$, that is $f(x)=f(x+1)$.

Also, $f([0,1])=\left[0, \frac12\right]$

Since 
$$I(k)=[k\pi, k\pi + 1]$$

is a closed interval with length $1$, hence $$f(I(k))=\left[0, \frac12\right].$$